# installing app engine plugin in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install app engine plugin into eclipse but when put the url http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5  and installion began it comes with the error as listed below
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i was having some problems in installing plugins in eclipse 3.5. Then i changed to eclipse 3.6 thinks worked like charm. I guess you are using linux.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be related to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309059). What version of Eclipse are you running? And what version of Java?

Comment: @user667340 - The bug report states that the issue is fixed in 3.6. Updating your Eclipse should solve your problems.